# Change CSS letter-spacing through Chrome Extension

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a Chrome extension that will add extra letter spacing on all websites (letter-spacing: 4px). It also uses placekitten to replace all images to kitten photos. However, when testing it out, it didn't work. Here's what I have so far:

manifest.json

```
    {
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Spatial Intelligence",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Dope vibes for all",

  "content_scripts": [{
    "css": ["styles.css"],
    "js": ["content.js"],
    "matches": ["http://*/*"]
  }]
     "run_at" : "document_start";

}
```

content.js

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0, l = images.length; i < l; i++) {
  images[i].src = 'http://placekitten.com/' + images[i].width + '/' + images[i].height;
}
```

styles.css

```
h1 {
  letter-spacing: 4px !important;
}

h2 {
  letter-spacing: 4px !important;
}

h3 {
  letter-spacing: 4px !important;
}

body {
letter-spacing: 4px !important;
}
```

I have some basic experience with HTML/CSS, but this is my first time trying to develop a chrome extension. Does anyone have any insight?

Comment: Can you explain more specifically "didn't work"? Preferably with a website example.

Comment: This is an invalid manifest.json: 1) remove `;` after "document_start", 2) move the entire "run_at" line inside "content_scripts" block, 3) replace `"http://*/*"` with `"<all_urls>"`, 4) at document_start there'll be nothing in the document, no images either so you'll want to use MutationObserver to detect the images being added.

Comment: better use `"document_end"` for `run_at` or just don't define `run_at` to default it to `"document_idle"`

Comment: @Xan I loaded the unpacked extension and turned on developer mode, but it did not affect any of my subsequently opened tabs. Images weren't replaced, letter spacing remained normal.

Comment: @wOxxOm  I made the changes you suggested and it works now! Thank you so, so much!